# SqlReader return decimal field to four places

Tags: sqldatareader

Good day!

I have some couple of columns i am returning from sql and binding to listview. However, a particular column of type money is sql returns to four decimal places when i use

```
myreader["columnNAme"].ToString();
```

IF the name value is 0.00. It will return 0.0000. Pls is this normal? Where do i go wrong? How do it maintain the correct format place and pass to listview column as string pls? tried converting to decimal using decimal.parse() but its rounding to whole number. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: mySqlDataReader.GetDecimal(2) ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THank you. I use the following.

```
public static string FormatMoney(object money)
{
     return Validator.ParseDecimal(money).ToString("###,###,##0.00");

}

FormatMoney(myreader["Columnname"]);
```